# can't get referer in iOS

Tags: javascript, java

I'm using this code on my page:

```
window.location.href="url"
```

When I use

request.getHeader("Referer")
to get referer, I get null in iOS, but in other devices, it's available

i have tried

```
request.getHeader("referer")
```

AND

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = 'url';
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
```

It not work to use in iOS

What should I do?

Comment: `request.getHeader("referer")` where is this executed? `request` is not available in the browser (afaik). Are you using a library?

Comment: request.getHeader("referer")  is executed on the Java back

Comment: I've added Java tag back, as it was unclear if you had confused JS and Java

Comment: My project is a springboot project, i  used  "window.location.href"  in the front Jump to the page,And send a get request through Ajax,receive the request in the back and use referer to do a function of anti-theft chain,but the referer is null

Answer (score -1):

Try to:

```
var referrer = document.referrer;
```

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer